# Как найти вывести только те элементы списка, которые начинаются на заданную букву?

Tags: c

Есть список который состоит из структуры и указателя.
В структуре есть поле со строкой.
Как реализовать вывод на экран по те элементы списка, у которого данное поле структуры начинается на заданную с клавиатуры букву. 
пример:

```
struct A {
    char name[10];
};
struct List {
    A a;
    List * next;
};
```

и функция у которой происходит ввод буквы с клавиатуры и которая перебирает все элементы.
Я себе представлял это так:

```
void func (List * begin) {
    List * AA = begin;
    char letter;
    printf("Please, put big letter: ");
    scanf("%s\n", letter);

    while(AA) {
        if(AA->a.name[0] == letter) {
            printf("%s\n", AA->a.name);
        }
        AA = AA->next;
    }
}
```

но программа крашится при запуске.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то, можно:

```
scanf("%c",&letter);
```

Но! ввод *буферизован*, так что вам нужно нажать еще и Enter, чтобы функция приступила к работе...

Answer (score 0):

нашел решение с помощью функции `_getch()`
Тоисть меняем строку

```
scanf("%s\n", letter);
```

На строку

```
letter = _getch();
```

Ошибка исчезла. Но вот вопрос, почему мы не можем обычным `scanf` считать букву, всё же меня интересует

Comment: Попробуйте так scanf("%c\n",&letter);

Comment: просто сканф принимает указатель на переменную, а вы по значению передовали. поэтому и было исключение.